# C error expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strcat, function-definition

I am trying to implement my version of `strcat`. However, I get below warning and my code crashes while running. I am passing `&p` from `main` to make permanent changes to variable `p` in the `main` function.

Warning:

```
note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[10]’
```

Code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void mystrcat(char **p, char *q)
{
    while (**p != '\0')
    {
        *p++;
    }

    while (*q != '\0')
    {
        **p = *q;
        (*p)++;
        q++;
    }
    *p = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char p[10] = "ravi";
    char q[12] = "ra";

    mystrcat(&p, q);
    printf("%s", p);
}
```

Comment: try `char *p="ravi";`

Comment: @tstanisl that would be UB.

Comment: No, I can not  change char p[10]="ravi";   that is not what I wanted as I want my program to run in any scenario even if  array of char is given instead of pointer to char

Comment: Perhaps a good first step would be looking at the interface of the standard `strcat`. Does it have a `char **` somewhere? Why do you think you need one?

Comment: Are you planning to use this with dynamically allocated arrays too? Is that the reason why the first argument is a `char**`, to be able to modify that pointer? If that is the case, you should also pass the allocated size, otherwise there's no need to pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @alex01011, your're right, I haven't noticed that memory is modified via `p`.

Comment: there are lots of mistakes in this code.  It would be a lot simpler to make the function have parameters `(char *p, char const *q)` , then this issue wouldn't even arise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a *pointer to a pointer to char*, just pass a ***pointer to char***, it will also make the modification permanent. That's pretty much how the `string.h` `strcat` works. Maybe also check for **NULL** pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *mystrcat(char *p, char *q)
{
    char *ptr = p; /* so you dont alter p's initial address */

    if (p == NULL || q == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        ptr++;
    }

    while(*q != '\0')
    {
        *ptr = *q;
        ptr++; /* you dont have to dereference */
        q++;
    }
    *ptr = '\0';

    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
    char p[100]="hello";
    char q[12]="world";

    mystrcat(p, q);
    printf("%s", p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am surprised why I do not need  pointer to a pointer to char to make changes permanent. Think of a scenario where  you want to swap two variables in a function permanently, you have to pass its address, then why not in this case?

Comment: `char *ptr = p; /* so you dont alter p's initial address , in case of a dynamic string */` does not make sense, `p` in `mystrcat` is already a copy of `p` in `main` (decayed to a pointer). No need to make an additional copy.

Comment: @Ravi `char *p` literally is passing the address of the characters in the string

Comment: @mch yes you are right indeed, I forgot to change the return type, to `char *`. Edited.

Comment: @alex01011 I still see no reason for this line. Just remove it and use `p` instead of `ptr` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: @mch, consider the following, https://godbolt.org/z/896r7cqcc. Now p, points to the end of string, so a function like `printf()` or `puts()` will only see `\0`.

Comment: @alex01011 And what's the difference to your version? https://godbolt.org/z/cbfsaEcxv If you print the return value of it, it does not matter if the function works on a copy of the pointer like I suggest or on a copy of the copy of the pointer, like you did, `printf("%s", p);` works in both cases and your version creates a copy of the copy of the pointer and tell the reader in the comment something that's not true.

Comment: @mch Yeah I'm sorry for messing the `return`. You are making this a big deal anyways, this how the `strcat` from `string.h` works. Appreciate the dvote btw.

Answer (score 6):

The variable `p` is declared as having the type `char[10]`

```
char p[10]="ravi";
```

So the expression `&p` in this call

```
mystrcat(&p, q);
```

has the type `char ( * )[10]`.

However the corresponding function parameter has the type `char **`.

```
void mystrcat(char **p, char *q)
```

and there is no implicit conversion from the type `char ( * )[10]` to the type `char **`. So the compiler issues an error.

You could call your function the following way

```
char *tmp = p;
mystrcat( &tmp, q );
```

But in any case the function is incorrect at least due to this while loop

```
while(**p != '\0')
{
    *p++;
}
```

because the expression

```
*p++
```

is equivalent to the expression

```
*( p++ )
```

while you need the expression

```
( *p )++
```

or

```
++*p
```

Or the last statement shall be

```
**p = '\0';
```

instead of

```
*p = '\0';
```

There is no any sense to declare the first function parameter as having the type `char **` instead of the type `char *` as it is declared in the standard C function `strcat`.

```
char * strcat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

Moreover the second parameter shall have the qualifier `const` because the corresponding string is not changed within the function. And the function should return a pointer to the destination string.

So the function can look the following way

```
char * mystrcat( char *p, const char *q )
{
    char *s = p;

    while ( *s ) ++s;

    while ( ( *s++ = *q ) != '\0' ) ++q;

    return p;
}
```

and be called like

```
puts( mystrcat( p, q ) );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * mystrcat( char *p, const char *q )
{
    char *s = p;

    while ( *s ) ++s;

    while ( ( *s++ = *q ) != '\0' ) ++q;

    return p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char p[10] = "ravi";
    char q[12] = "ra";
    
    puts( mystrcat( p, q ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ravira
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass a pointer that points to each individual character of the array:

```
int main()
{
 char p[10]="ravi5";
 char q[12]="ra54";
 
 char* pPointer = p;
 char** pPointerPointer = &pPointer;

 mystrcat(pPointerPointer, q);
 printf("%s", p);
 return 0;
}
```

Note: In your strcat function you missed the parenthesis:

```
while(**p != '\0')
{
 (*p)++;
}
```